# unwanted <!--html_preserve--> in Rpres markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm getting unwanted  in the rmarkdown output of Hmisc::describe when using Rstudio Rpres format:

````
test
========================================================
author: 
date: 
autosize: true

First Slide
========================================================

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(Hmisc)
html(describe(cars$dist))
```
````

Produces this:

[image]

However, a regular Rmarkdown is not affected:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Some user"
date: "January 13, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(Hmisc)
html(describe(cars$dist))    
```
````

Not sure how to troubleshoot. Rpres? Pandoc? Hmisc?

Comment: I don't have any experience with `Rpres` but may be worth trying adding `results='asis'` in the chunk header.

Comment: Thanks Frank. `results = 'asis'` doesn't help. I tried pasting the content of `Hmisc::html(describe(cars$dist))` wrapped in `<!--html_preserve-->` `<!--/html_preserve-->` and that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rpres was an early experiment for presentations based on Markdown, and its development has been halted pretty much since [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) was introduced in 2014. Rpres is not R Markdown, but a completely different implementation, e.g., it is not based on Pandoc. Tricks like `htmltools::htmlPreserve()` won't work in Rpres, and that is why `Hmisc::html()` doesn't work. I recommend that you stop using Rpres, and consider other frameworks based on R Markdown.

Comment: Thanks Yihui!  Are you aware of other templates besides ioslides, slidy, revealjs?  Is slidify still being developed?

Comment: AFAIK the development of slidify has pretty much stopped a couple of years ago: https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/graphs/contributors I developed the xaringan package in 2016 and haven't been bored so far: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan :)